# git username change not reflected in webstorm/teamcity

Tags: git, github, teamcity, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to get TeamCity, WebStorm, git and GitHub all communicating.  It's working, with the exception that all checkins show up with the username "scott.beeson".  When I checked my .gitconfig, the user name was "scott beeson".  Obviously, it replaced the space with a period, that's no big deal.  I am now attempting to make it match my GitHub username, which is completely different anyway.  I've modified the file as well as tried the following command:

```
git config --global user.name "githubUserName"
```

If I exit the command prompt and launch a new one, calling "git config --global user.name" does show the correct (new) username.  But when I do a commit and push from WebStorm, TeamCity still shows scott.beeson.

I also tried reinitializing the repo from the command line.  Still didn't change anything.

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens when you run git config --get user.name ?

Comment: It returns the updated, new name.